# Changing the header content of another page javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code where it changes the image on the other page

```
<div class="imgbx">
                <button onclick="window.location.href='index.html?image=images/xr-black.jpg&tit=XR-black'" >Invisible button</button>
                <img src="images/xr-black.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

and this is the other page part

```
<img  id="image" src="images/xr-blue.jpg" alt="Grill" class="img" >
    <script>
                            const queryString = window.location.search;
                            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
                            const image = urlParams.get('image')
                            const tit = urlParams.get('tit')
                            
                            document.getElementById('image').src = image;
                            document.getElementById('tit').innerHTML = tit;
    
                        </script>   
    <h1 id="tit"></h1>
```

Now the image is changing just fine but I just can't seem to make the h1 tag to work and change the content inside

Comment: Minor difference... The `<img>` element exists when the JS executes, but the `<h1>` element does not because it's after the JS code.  Move it to before the JS code.  Refer to the duplicate for more information.  Note that this would be producing an error in the browser's development console.  You should always check there for errors and make use of the browser's debugging tools to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase, you are saying that when you try and change the header on another page to match the image that changes on another page, the image changes however the header is not changing.

Have you tried using a boolean to trigger the header color change?

if imageColor = true{
h1="000000"};